# Auto_execok problem on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, tcl

I have a problem:
the `auto_execok` command doesn't work on Cygwin platform as expected.
It cannot find anything from your `PATH` enviroment variable, as

```
info body auto_execok
"...
    foreach dir [split $path {;}] {
"
```

It thinks by default that `;` is right separator, but Cygwin uses `:`!
How to elegantly overcome this problem?
I don't want to change `PATH` variable as other programs/scripts could correctly use `:` as it should be for Cygwin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a mix of `set ar [info args auto_execok]`, `set bd [info body auto_execok]`, 
some regsub on body with `set cygdir [exec cygpath -a $wdir]` and `eval proc auto_exeok {$ar} {$bd}` to obtain needed result.

However, for the moment, I'm not yet ready with the complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a proper Cygwin-aware build of Tcl? As you've found, a straight Windows build runs into problems precisely because the Cygwin environment is a sort of mix between Unix and Windows. (This an example of why we don't fully support doing things in Cygwin; it gets some love from time to time, but it's not a primary platform because it is fully of fiddly complexities.) That said, this is the sort of question which it is almost certainly better to ask on [comp.lang.tcl](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.tcl/topics) as that's got a community likely to be able to help with this sort of thing.

Also, what patch-level of Tcl is this? This matters because the level of support has most certainly varied over time…

Comment: Might be interesting if http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/315.html should reflect a cygwin environment?

Comment: patchLevel - 8.4.1. However I've just checked 8.5.9 - the same as auto_execok is hardcoded.

Comment: >>Have you got a proper Cygwin-aware build of Tcl? --- Where can I get one?

Comment: 8.5.9 is pretty recent (8.5.10 was only released on Friday). What happens is that Tcl detects the type of platform it's on and uses the “right” definition of `auto_execok` for that system. The rules for standard Windows are radically different to Unix, but I really don't grok exactly where Cygwin stands; I have never used it. (Do visit c.l.t; the people who _know_ this one are more likely to see it there.)

Comment: I have the version of Tcl that comes with Cygwin, and it has the same problem. Strange that in all the years I've been using Tcl under cygwin, I never noticed it. I guess I don't use the autoexec functionality much.

Comment: Donal Fellows: The reasons are known. The question is how to overcome this. One way is to redefine it with "proc auto_execok {name} {... split ":" ...} Are there any other ways? Is auto_execok implemented in tclshXX.dll/wishXX.dll libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the native tcl version of auto_execok with one that will resolve the correct path. We can use the fact that the original auto_execok will find the cygpath.exe and in one fell swoop tell use that the current script is running windows and it is setup for cygwin. Once that it is known we can wrap the original auto_execok proc with one that will use cygpath.exe to resolve the true windows path.  I have used the try command so this is for 8.5 and above but this can be written using catch for lower versions of tcl. Also because subst command is used the path to cygpath is hardcoded into the new auto_execok proc so lookup only happens once. Also only allow this code to run once.  So as example
before code below runs

`puts "[ auto_execok tar ]"`

gives
 "/usr/bin/tar"

after code is run auto_execok is wrapped:

`puts "[ auto_execok tar ]"`

gives (on my machine):

"C:/cygwin/bin/tar.EXE"

```
if { [string length [ auto_execok cygpath ] ] } { 
set paths [ split $env(PATH) ";" ]
set cygexecpath "" 
foreach p $paths { 
    set c  [file join $p cygpath.exe ] 
    puts "checking for $c "
    if {[file exists $c ] } { 
        set cygexecpath [file join $p cygpath.exe ]
        break
    } 
}
if { $cygexecpath eq "" } { 
    puts "unable to find true path to [auto_execok cygpath.exe ]"
}
# rename original proc so we can use it in our wrapper proc 
rename ::auto_execok ::auto_execok_orig
uplevel #0 [subst -nocommands {proc auto_execok { path } {
    try {
        set path [auto_execok_orig \$path ] 
        if { \$path ne \"\" } {
            set path [string trim [exec $cygexecpath -w \$path ] ]
        }
    } on error { a b } {
        set path \"\" 
    } 
    return \$path
} } ] 
puts "[info body auto_execok ] "
```

}